# What is the correct Smartsheet formula for retrieving the number of appointments from today plus 7

Tags: formula, countif, smartsheet-api

I have a table in Smartsheets that has bookings in it.

If the appointment is confirmed it changes the status to scheduled. It also has a date assigned to it. I'm trying to use countifs to see how many are scheduled for the next 7 days.

This is the formula i have.

```
=COUNTIFS([Shoot Setup]:[Shoot Setup], "Styleshoots", [Date start]:[Date 
start], >=TODAY(7))
```

This does not give me the correct value.

If i dont have the 7 modifier then it gives me the correct value for items scheduled from today.

But i want to just see the total for today plus 6 days 7 days in total.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you've posted will return the count of rows where:

- **Shoot Setup** = "Styleshoots"

AND

- **Date start** is greater than or equal to *seven days from today*

Try using this formula instead:

`=COUNTIFS([Shoot Setup]:[Shoot Setup], "Styleshoots", [Date start]:[Date start], >=TODAY(), [Date start]:[Date start], <=TODAY(7))`

This formula will return the count of rows where:

- **Shoot Setup** = "Styleshoots"

AND

- **Date start** is *greater than or equal to Today*

AND

- **Date start** is *less than or equal to 7 days from today*

Comment: Thankyou for this, this worked but i have <=TODAY(7)) this gives me the correct value i am looking for.

Comment: Happy I could help! Thanks for the confirmation; for the benefit of others in the future, I've updated my answer to reflect that `<=TODAY(7)` met the requirement you described.